# SparkSQL isn't ordering correctly in window specification

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sql-order-by, window-functions

I'm running spark in distributed mode and having some trouble with windowing. Let's see a specific case in my Dataframe:

```
df.where($"client_id" === 221689).orderBy($"sequence_num".asc).show

+---------+------------+-----+
|client_id|sequence_num|state|
+---------+------------+-----+
|   221689|     6417377|REPBI|
|   221689|     6417378|DESBL|
|   221689|     6417379|REPOS|
|   221689|      920002|SUSUN|
|   221689|      920003|BLOQU|
|   221689|      920004|SUSBI|
|   221689|      920005| BAJA|
+---------+------------+-----+
```

It is clear that the ordering isn't working properly. When I apply a window, the same bad ordering is applied:

```
val client_window = Window.partitionBy($"client_id").orderBy($"sequence_num").rowsBetween(Long.MinValue, Long.MaxValue)
df.withColumn("last_state", last($"state") over client_window).where($"client_id" === 221689).show

+---------+------------+-----+----------+
|client_id|sequence_num|state|last_state|
+---------+------------+-----+----------+
|   221689|     6417377|REPBI|      BAJA|
|   221689|     6417378|DESBL|      BAJA|
|   221689|     6417379|REPOS|      BAJA|
|   221689|      920002|SUSUN|      BAJA|
|   221689|      920003|BLOQU|      BAJA|
|   221689|      920004|SUSBI|      BAJA|
|   221689|      920005| BAJA|      BAJA|
+---------+------------+-----+----------+
```

The value of `last_state` should be `REPOS` as is the state of the latest sequence number, but is calculating `BAJA` which is incorrect.

I'm working with Spark 1.6.3 in a HDP 2.6.1 cluster.

Comment: The `sequence_num` column is likely to be of string type. Cast it to numeric first -

Comment: Sorry, my bad.... It worked well with ```sequence_num``` as long.